# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and I was doing this [Leetcode Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/) and having trouble understanding why I am getting the attribute error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' (Line 24 in deleteDuplicates). Both noDuplicatesList/Itr are correctly assigned a value, so their attribute 'next' should work...

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if (head is None):
            return head

        # first element has a non-null value
        # noDuplicatesList points to list head
        # noDuplicatesItr traces list items
        noDuplicatesList = ListNode(head.val)
        noDuplicatesItr = noDuplicatesList

        # iterate down original list
        while (head.next.val != None):
            if (head.val != head.next.val):
                noDuplicatesItr.next = ListNode(head.next.val)
            head = head.next
            noDuplicatesItr = noDuplicatesItr.next
        return noDuplicatesList
```

Comment: Is it because the `ListNode` class is commented out? (EDIT: Forget what I've just commented - it looks like the site has the exact same boilerplate code at the top)

Comment: If it is impossible for `head.next` to be `None`, what is it for the end of the list?

Comment: Please add the proper traceback: there are lots of lines where a variable has an attribute `.next`. Mentiong line 24 is of no use, without line numbering.

Comment: It also appears that line 24 is the line where the `noDuplicatesList` variable is returned?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: You need to show us how you are using it - please post a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal).

Answer (score 0):

You should not be explicitly using the `ListNode` class. The `instance.next` is and instance of `ListNode` as well if it's not `None`. I would imagine the error is being picked up in the `while` loop condition:

```py
while (head.next.val != None):
```

This is inflexible because it *requires* `head.next` to not be `None`, when that isn't a guarantee. What I might do instead is to check `if node.next is not None`:

```py
while True:
    if head.next is not None:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
        # maybe break or return
    head = head.next
```

It's considered more pythonic for `while` loops to use `while True`, and let some inner control flow dictate when the loop will break

Answer (score 0):

Let debug your code with sample input
`1->1->2`

```py
while (head.next.val != None):
  if (head.val != head.next.val):
      noDuplicatesItr.next = ListNode(head.next.val)
  head = head.next
  noDuplicatesItr = noDuplicatesItr.next # this line cause problem
```

In the first loop, `noDuplicatesItr` assigned to `noDuplicatesItr.next` and value of `noDuplicatesItr.next` is `None`

In the second loop, if condition is True but the statement become `None.next = ....`

Here is my accepted solution based on your approach:

```py
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if head is None:
            return head 

        noDuplicatesList = ListNode(0)
        headNoDuplicatesList = noDuplicatesList # points to list head

        while head: # head.next.val will fail in the end of the list, last.next is None
            if (head and not head.next) or (head.val != head.next.val): # head and not head.next check for the lastest element, just add it.
                noDuplicatesList.val = head.val
                if head.next: 
                    noDuplicatesList.next = ListNode(0) # first, initialize next node
                    noDuplicatesList = noDuplicatesList.next # second, move to next node
            head = head.next

        return headNoDuplicatesList
```

Answer (score -1):

a brute force solution.

```
try:
  head = head.next
except:
  continue
```